# How to get lastest created_at and updated_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

#### My code

```
$datas = DB::table('patrol_gate_surveillance_transactions as a')
    ->leftJoin('client_locations as b','a.client_location_id', 'b.id')
    ->leftJoin('clients as c', 'b.client_id', 'c.id')
    ->select('a.client_location_id as location_id', 'b.name as location_name', 'c.name as client_name',
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 1 THEN employee_qty ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_in'),
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 2 THEN employee_qty ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_out')
    )
    ->groupBy('location_id', 'location_name', 'client_name')
    ->get();
```

I want to get the last `created_at` and `updated_at` only

#### My table

[image: table]

## dd()

i need created_at and updated_at only for parsing data to blade
[image]

Comment: Please dont post images for text information

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are not using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships), but please, use them, that is the idea of using Eloquent...

If you just want the last row (based on `created_at`), you must do:

```php
$datas = DB::table('patrol_gate_surveillance_transactions as a')
    ->leftJoin('client_locations as b','a.client_location_id', 'b.id')
    ->leftJoin('clients as c', 'b.client_id', 'c.id')
    ->select('a.client_location_id as location_id', 'b.name as location_name', 'c.name as client_name',
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 1 THEN employee_qty ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_in'),
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 2 THEN employee_qty ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_out')
    )
    ->groupBy('location_id', 'location_name', 'client_name')
    ->latest()
    ->first();
```

I have used [`latest()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#latest-oldest) and [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table).

- `latest`: it will just do `ORDER BY created_at DESC`
- `first`: you want to get only one row, so you use `first` (it will return a Model, not a Collection)

Comment: instead of pulling data based on created_at , I just want to grab the last cretaed_at & updated_at to parsing to view

Comment: I do not see the difference of `instead of pulling data based on` and `I just want to grab the last`, what do you mean? if you just literally want `created_at` and `updated_at` as a result, you must update the select to `->select('created_at', 'updated_at')`, so it will just return those 2 columns

Comment: ->select('created_at', 'updated_at')

will interfere with the groupby I've created, because I want to do a groupby based on location_id

Comment: Then how are you supposed to get that data...

Answer (score 0):

After joining tables:

```
DB::table( ... )
    ->latest('id') /* order id by decending */
    ->first() /* get the first row */
    ->value('created_at');
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

Comment: No need to `->first()` (get the data and have it in memory) and then `->value(xxx)`, when you can just do `->latest(x)->value(y)`

Comment: i can't add created_at into SELECT because it will affect GROUPBY,

Comment: .a.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY